# updating table with an unknown input name

Tags: php, mysql

**Background:**

I have a table of "sales" on my website. I'm trying to update the delivery status manually from the table(in the HTML).
I have put the status as a text input with the value of itself(basically, the input is already filled in until I change what's written inside).

the names of each status are made with the same php script that inputs them and made like this($name increases by 1 every line of the table and starts with 0):

```
   echo "</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"status_$num\" value=" .$row['productStatus']. "></td></tr>";
```

so the names for each status are: status_0 status_1 status_2...

**my problem:**

I want to use the main button for all of the inputs(they are placed in a form) and I can't manage to figure out a way to do that.

this is my table:
[image: table]

How can I get the $_POST[''] of the input that was changed?
is there a simple way to do that or should I just add a button for each line for each status with the same name and then loop for each name:`while(!isset($_POST["submit_status_$name"])){...}`.

*If any part is a little confusing please explain what you don't understand and I will gladly clarify (:*

thank you!

Comment: How many status fields are there and you cannot do this you must know what you are asking. You could have another hidden post variable that tell you the number. But you should think of another way to exchange data

Comment: @nbk there is an unknown amount of status fields,  each is generated with a unique name

Comment: Define arrays in the input fields like here in the frist comment https://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.post.php